# Downloaded Images are not showing in Gallery, Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I am working on an App where I am Downloading Images and Storing them into Internal Storage. Facing issue when showing downloaded images in Gallery on Nougat installed Device.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)

    {
        Log.e("-->", " >= 14");
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{event.getFilePath()}, new String[]{".jpg"}, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            /*
             *   (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener#onScanCompleted(java.lang.String, android.net.Uri)
             */
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.e("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.e("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
            }
        });
    } else

    {
        Log.e("-->", " < 14");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
    }
}
  public static File getStorageFolder(){
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory 
           (Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"Camera");
  }
```

**Note**: Getting problem only on Nougat Device

Any Help will be Appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a permission for external storage?

Comment: `.jpg` is not a MIME type. Beyond that, where exactly does `getFilePath()` point? If your file is on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), other apps, including the media scanner have no access to it.

Comment: I have updated method details in question

Comment: @Mike I have external storage permission in manifest.

Comment: try putting MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{yourFile}, null, null); (yourFile being a File Object) after downloading image

Answer (score 0):

**".jpg"** is not a valid MIME type for image.

Use mime type array

```
new String[]{"image/jpeg", "image/png"}
```

instead of

```
new String[]{".jpg"}
```